# CXF Client Configuration: Why are the WSA Elements not being added to my request?

Tags: java, cxf, soap-client

I'm using `Apache CXF 2.4.10` with `wss4j 1.6.18` to consume an external webservice that requires me to add `WSA Security Addressing Elements`. According to the Apache's [WS-SecurityPolicy documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html), I need to configure an `AddressingProperties` and set it on `requestContext`. I am doing that however the element is not being added.
What am I doing wrong?

**MyClient.java**

```
public class MyClient
{

    protected SoapService getService()
    {

        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        factory.setServiceClass(SoapService.class);
        factory.setAddress(endpoint);

        service = (SoapService) factory.create();

        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(this.webServiceProxy);

        Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();

        //logging
        client.getOutInterceptors().add(new CustomLogInterceptor()); // allows me to see the SOAP Message just before it is sent

        //outbound config
        configureWSASecurity(factory, client, cxfEndpoint);

        configureTimestamp(cxfEndpoint, client);

        configureWSSecSignature(cxfEndpoint, client);

        configureWSSecEncrytion(cxfEndpoint, client);

        return service;
    }

    protected void configureWSASecurity(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory, Client client, Endpoint cxfEndpoint){
        factory.getFeatures().add(new WSAddressingFeature());

        AddressingBuilder addressingBuilder = AddressingBuilder.getAddressingBuilder();
        AddressingProperties maps = addressingBuilder.newAddressingProperties();

        AttributedURIType messageID = new AttributedURIType();
        messageID.setValue(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        maps.setMessageID(messageID);

        AttributedURIType replyTo = new AttributedURIType();
        replyTo.setValue("https://webservice.com/ping");
        EndpointReferenceType replyToRef = new EndpointReferenceType();
        replyToRef.setAddress(replyTo);
        maps.setReplyTo(replyToRef);

        Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider) this.webServiceProxy).getRequestContext();
        requestContext.put(JAXWSAConstants.CLIENT_ADDRESSING_PROPERTIES, maps);

    }

    protected void configureTimestamp(Endpoint cxfEndpoint, Client client){
        Map<String,Object> outProps = new HashMap<String,Object>();

        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.TIMESTAMP);
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.TTL_TIMESTAMP, "300");

        WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
        client.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
    }

    protected void configureWSSecSignature(Endpoint cxfEndpoint, Client client){
        Map<String,Object> outProps = new HashMap<String,Object>();

        WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
        client.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
    }

    @Override
    public String ping(String input)
    {
        return this.getService().ping(input);
    }

}
```

**Here are the missing request elements that are missing:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-26035916F4AB4AF63814481608229281">
            <wsu:Created>2015-11-22T02:53:42.927Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2015-11-22T02:58:42.927Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <ping xmlns="https://webservice.com/">
         <ping>success</ping>
      </ping>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**This is what the request is supposed to look like:**

```
<wsa:MessageID xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
wsu:Id="id-4">urn:uuid:bc57cb92-6a37-4e99-ad2d-1a0ad718264e</wsa:MessageID>

<wsa:ReplyTo xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-5">

<wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
</wsa:ReplyTo>

<wsa:To xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
wsu:Id="id-6">http://localhost:1835/webservice/Service.asmx</wsa:To>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the **addressingFeature** is not added before`factory.create()` is called, the `wsAddressingFeature` needs to be initialized to the `client bus`.

I added this lined of code to the `configureWSASecurity` method:

```
WSAddressingFeature wsAddressingFeature = new WSAddressingFeature();
wsAddressingFeature.initialize(client, client.getBus());
```